# Graphileon Interactor: how to set style for a node with a given string property

Tags: graphileon

What is the right format to define a style selector for a node with a specific string property?

In Interactor one can define different styles for nodes and relationships based on their Labels and properties ([doc](http://docs.graphileon.com/interactor/For_Dashboard_Users/Styling.html#page_Editor)). The example shows how to select nodes with label MyLabel and the value of property myParam larger than 5.

When trying to create a style for nodes that have a property 'kind' set to a given string 'Needle_Mover', the style is applied to all nodes with the same label, even if their property string is different.

For example:

```
:Program                        -> red
:Program[kind=='Needle_Mover']  -> blue
```

All nodes with label Program will show blue.

I suspect it is a syntax mistake on my side... I have tried with a single = as well.

Comment: It seems I see inconsistent behaviour, after reloading the browser some of the colors change but it still is not what I expect, so I would like to make sure what the correct syntax is, from there conclude if it is a bug or my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following style selectors should work

for a style for a specific value of a property

```
:Program[myProp=abc]
```

for a style to be applied when a property exists

```
:Program[myProp]
```

for numeric properties we also have

```
:Program[myNumericProp > 5]  
:Program[myNumericProp = 5]  
:Program[myNumericProp < 5]
```

Comment: single = sign and no quotes... that was it ;-) Thanks